# CSS: Div Background doesn't show

Tags: css

I have given it a width/height; path should be correct relative to CSS. It's one big div, containing some others, I didn't know if that's relevant, so I just copied them in as well.

HTML:

```
<div id="fenster"> 
  <div id="links">
    <img src="logo.gif" height="220" width="260">
    <div id="menu">
      ...   
    </div>

    <div id="social">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fenster {
  background-image: "hintergrund.jpg";
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 700px; 
  width: 1200px;
  margin-top: 100px;  
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;   
}
```

Comment: Your `#fenster` has position `static`, it does not require `top` or `left` declarations. Are you absolutely sure the image is loaded correctly? Try opening Developer Tools (in Chrome or Firefox), inspecting the element and then checking if it resolves the image correctly. EDIT: As Sachin has noticed you're missing `url`.

Answer (score 4):

Your `background-image` property doesn't have the valid value. You need to put the image path with `url` like this.

```
background-image: url("hintergrund.jpg");
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Haha! I always thought that the "url" part was something like a dummy-word, like "insert name here". Now it works perfectly fine!